# Next.js error when i run the code: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Here is my Next.js project, i have created it using npx create-next-app@latest blog, and its working fine for yesterday, until today when i try to run using yarn dev or npm run dev, both of them gives me this error, I am pretty sure i didnt use any useContext in my folder, can anyone help please:

```
Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Call Stack
Object.useContext
file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Coding/Nextjs/tutorial/blog/node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js (1618:21)
useContext
node_modules\next\dist\pages\_document.js (707:105)
renderWithHooks
file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Coding/Nextjs/tutorial/blog/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5658:16)
renderIndeterminateComponent
file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Coding/Nextjs/tutorial/blog/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5731:15)
renderElement
file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Coding/Nextjs/tutorial/blog/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (5946:7)
renderNodeDestructiveImpl
file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Coding/Nextjs/tutorial/blog/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6104:11)
renderNodeDestructive
file:///C:/Users/User/Documents/Coding/Nextjs/tutorial/blog/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js (6076:14)
```

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "blog",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "eslint": "8.36.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.2.4",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^10.11.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-request": "^5.2.0",
    "mongodb": "^5.2.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.0.3",
    "next": "^13.3.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.20.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.2",
    "swiper": "^9.1.1",
    "swr": "^2.1.1",
    "typewriter-effect": "^2.19.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
  }
}
```

_app.js file:

```
import '@/styles/globals.css'

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

_document.js file:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

here is the image:
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSKoM.png)

Comment: there's probably some accidental typos in other files other than _app or _document.   Good habit to start a version control (e.g. github) repo when u init the project so u know what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell from just your package.json but from the error message it mentioned `_document`.

Context must be implemented in `_app` and not `_document`, also make sure you are importing `useContext` from `react`

Comment: hmm wierd tho, i didnt implement useContext in _app or _document.js, wait let me update my code

Comment: can you help me to check the code again? I have tried multiple solutions but all of them does not work for me

Comment: Just checked, and spun up a new create-next-app and even with your packages I can't seem to reproduce. Could you throw your code into codesandbox?